# How to compare filenames in perl

Tags: perl

I have a list of filenames in the form `integer_Name.txt`. I want to return the filename with highest integer value. Is there any way this can be done in perl other than string comparison?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually called *natural sort*. There is module implementing it: [Sort::Naturally](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort%3a%3aNaturally)

To get highest value - you can sort and get last element:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Sort::Naturally;

my @names = (...);
my $name_with_biggest_number = (nsort(@names))[-1];
```

**Update - sort manually**

Using [map/sort/map idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). But will work only if there is single number in file name:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @names = (...);
my @sorted_names = 
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] } ## descending order
    map { [ $_, m/(\d+)/ ] }     ## extracting first number
    @names;
my $name_with_biggest_number = $sorted_names[0];
```

**Update - without sort**

Depending on input data it can be more efficient to avoid using `sort`. So you can explicitly code search of max number:

```
sub name_with_largest_number {
        my (@names) = @_;

        my $max_number = undef;
        my $name_with_max_number = undef;
        for my $name (@names) {
                my ($number) = ($name =~ m/(\d+)/);
                if (defined $number) {
                        if (! defined $max_number || $number > $max_number) {
                                $max_number = $number;
                                $name_with_max_number = $name;
                        }
                }
        }
        return $name_with_max_number;
}

print name_with_largest_number(...);
```

Comment: You need to install the module if you can.

Comment: @DarkKnight I've added "module free" implementation. But it can be much more "cryptic" and harder to support.

Comment: It is utter overkill to sort a whole list just to keep the highest number.

Comment: @tchrist Adding "sort free" variant.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Here's an alternative that does not need the expensive sort. Thanks @tchrist for pointing out how stupid the sort is.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @list = qw(
332_Name.txt
999_Name.txt
125_Name.txt
9_Name.txt
0066_Name.txt
);

my %mapping;
my $highest = 0;
foreach(map { m/(\d+)/; $mapping{$1} = $_; $1 } @list) {
  $highest = $_ if $_ > $highest;
}
print $mapping{$highest};
```

Comment: Here, too: it is massive overkill to sort a whole list just to keep the highest number.

Comment: @tchrist: Please propose an alternative.

Comment: Nevermind. You're right of course. It is rather late here and I should probably have gone to bed already.